# How to add knowledge of previous time steps to RNNs?

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I am setting up a single layer Gated Recurrent Unit (GRU) using [Keras for TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU) to predict time steps y_t given time steps X_t for a time series of times t,...,N. As I have knowledge of y at time t-1, how can I feed this to the network? Initially I thought of doing this through hidden states however these do not represent actual values of y and manually setting these will not improve the network unless when the value of y at t-1 is 0 (which corresponds to the default value for uninitialized hidden states).

Answer (score 0):

It is already happening and you don't have to go out of your way to do it. The hidden states are doing but yes, not the actual values are being used, their pattern is being learnt. That is a good thing because your model generalizes well.

If you are having problems with time-series data, consider increasing or decreasing window size, change the number of layers and units in them (first, judge whether overfitting is happening or underfitting) and employ dropout.